# How to highlight every Monday and add exceptions? CF / VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, calendar

So I'm currently building a calendar, which shows every Workday in a Year(top rows) and a list of people (column).

I want to be able to type somewhere (other sheet) the information like the person, which day should be highlighted through the year and also exceptions (timespans) where the wanted day should not be highlighted.

How could I solve this? Is there a a way to do that with conditional formatting or is VBA the way to go? How should I tackle this?

Calendar construction and on the bottom a possible form:

[image: Calendar construction and on the bottom a possible form]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's possible through conditional formatting, for example:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

- Select Sheet1, range `B2:whichever is your last cell in the matrix`
- Apply conditional formatting rule

  ```
  =AND(WEEKDAY(B$1,2)=1,$A2=Sheet2!$A$2,OR(B$1<Sheet2!$C$2,B$1>Sheet2!$D$2))
  ```

**Result:**

[image]

Notice how I used `WEEKDAY` and instead of typing which day, I refered to `1` (being a monday)

You should be able to tweak this around to suit your needs.

In general, a lot of these conditional formatting issues can be done without VBA. I notice a lot of questions that involve setting a background/fill color for a cell. But do notice that this is permanent instead of a conditional fill!